# Severe errors in solr configuration: Error loading class

Tags: windows-xp, tomcat, java, solr

Installed Solr on my Windows XP PC.  Tomcat seems to be working fine.  Cannot get Solr to work.  I noticed the TrieDateField is declared in a file called schema.xml in the SolrHome directory.  Any thoughts?

The Url http://localhost:8080/solr/ returns:

*HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: false in null ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldtype 'date' specified on field updated*

Here is an excerpt from the catalina log file:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.TrieDateField'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:273)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.TrieDateField
```

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue, after some digging I tried the following and it worked:

In your schema.xml file, change the class from "solr.TrieDateField" to "org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField".

Example:

```
<fieldType name="date" class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

I noticed this because of this comment in the file:

```
<!-- Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in the
   org.apache.solr.analysis package.
-->
```

Which is not where the TrieDateField class is located.

Hope this helps. 
-C

Comment: Thanks, I honest don't remember what my solution ultimately was, but this helps.